# How can I get all the file in a fold in a web application?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web

I publish my web application in tomcat server,in a picture fold I set it as anonymous access,so everyone can get the picture according to its name,such as `http://domainname/picturefold/abcdefg.jpg`.Now I afraid that if someone know all of the picture uploaded in a flod called `picturefold`,but do not know the real name of the file,Whether he can loop all my picture file or not?

Comment: If you have a system with no access control then of course it has no access control. The answer is a tautology.

Comment: @developerwjk, How can he do that when he do not know the picture name? I try to visit the fold it is wrong.`http://domainname/picturefold/`

Comment: They could guess the picture name, use a random word generator, or work for an ISP and have access to traffic logs that shows someone else made a request to the page `http://domainname/picturefold/nobody could ever guess this filename.jpg`